# extracting string from bracket using boost spirit

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I have the following string:

```
%%DocumentNeededResources: CMap (90pv-RKSJ-UCS2C)
```

I want to parse it and store/extract the `90pv-RKSJ-UCS2C` string which is in bracket.

My rule is as follows:

```
std::string strLinesRecur = "%%DocumentNeededResources: CMap (90pv-RKSJ-UCS2C)";
std::string strStartTokenRecur;
std::string token_intRecur;
bool bParsedLine1 = qi::phrase_parse(strLinesRecur.begin(), strLinesRecur.end(), +char_>>+char_,':', token_intRecur, strStartTokenRecur);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you thought a skipper is a split delimiter. It's quite the opposite ([Boost spirit skipper issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965)).

In this rare circumstance I think I'd prefer a regular expression. But, since you asked here's the spirit take:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dd8fcd90bd91772c)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main() {
    std::string const line = "%%DocumentNeededResources: CMap (90pv-RKSJ-UCS2C)";

    auto first = line.begin(), last = line.end();

    std::string label, token;
    bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(
            first, last, 
            qi::lexeme [ "%%" >> +~qi::char_(":") ] >> ':' >> qi::lexeme["CMap"] >> '(' >> qi::lexeme[+~qi::char_(')')] >> ')',
            qi::space,
            label, token);

    if (ok)
        std::cout << "Parse success: label='" << label << "', token='" << token << "'\n";
    else
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";

    if (first!=last)
        std::cout << "Remaining unparsed input: '" << std::string(first, last) << "'\n";
}
```

Prints

```
Parse success: label='DocumentNeededResources', token='90pv-RKSJ-UCS2C'
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so assuming we are given the following `using` and alias namespace directives:

```
using namespace boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phx = boost::phoenix;
```

And given the string:

```
std::string strLinesRecur = "%%DocumentNeededResources: CMap (90pv-RKSJ-UCS2C)";
```

We would like to extract the "code" inside the parenthesis into `res`:

```
std::string res;
```

One way to do this is to use `boost::phoenix::ref` as semantic action. 
So given a code grammar as:

```
using boost::spirit::ascii::alnum;
auto code = copy(+(alnum | char_('-')));
```

(Which is along the lines of what in a regex would be `[a-zA-Z\-]`)

We can create our own grammar for the whole string:

```
using boost::spirit::ascii::alpha;
auto grammar = copy(
    (char_('%') >> char_('%') >> +alpha >> char_(':')) 
        >> +alpha >> char_('(') >> as_string[lexeme[code]][phx::ref(res) = _1] >> char_(')'));
```

Which parses anything that begins with two `%`, follows with some alphabetic characters and a `:`, then follows with some "code" within parenthesis.

The whole point to this is `as_string[lexeme[code]][phx::ref(res) = _1]`. If we break it down: `lexeme[code]` just says to treat the parsed `code` as an atomic unit, `as_string` "returns" the result as `std::string` (as opposed to `std::vector<char>`) and `[phx::ref(res) = _1]` uses semantic actions to store the parsed string into `res` (`_1` is a placeholder for the first match within that grammar).

In this case spaces are skipped by the following call:

```
using boost::spirit::ascii::blank;
phrase_parse(begin(strLinesRecur), end(strLinesRecur), grammar, blank);
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/faa5ae3fa395a43d)

This is of course just an example of a grammar that would fit the string.

<sub>Note: `copy` refers to `qi::copy` and it's one way to be able to store pieces of grammars like in the objects `code` and `grammar`. Without that the use of `auto` will fail (probably with a segmentation fault).</sub>

Comment: Hmm I wasn't aware of `qi::copy` o.O I always use `boost::proto::deep_copy` or `BOOST_SPIRIT_AUTO` (which has the benefit of working in c++03 as well).

Comment: Here I offer you my (vastly :)) simplified version based on your take: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/baba2953f7735d29)**